# tmp/krb5cc_[uid] is not getting purged regularly (kerberos credentials cache)

Tags: linux, tmp, kerberos

A user wasn't able to authenticate using Kerberos because it wasn't able to create /tmp/krb5cc_[uid]. This was because /tmp ran out of inode space, as there were innumerable Kerberos credential cache files. Some were older than 2 years. Why is the credential cache is not getting deleted after use? Is this a problem with the user profile?